# Python - Is there more efficient way to convert the string values in Dict to get unique numbers for each str

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

I have a data which consist of 2 million records, I am trying to convert the values to number and save it in a dictionary. Then use that dictionary to use it as a lookup. All to reduce the size of the file.

the data looks like this

```
[{
'a' : ['one','two'],
'b' : 'fine',
'c' : ['help']},
{
'a' : ['four','hen'],
'b' : 'happy',
'c' : ['mouse']},
{
'a' : ['two','hen'],
'b' : 'fine'}.......]
```

```
def convertDataToNumber(newdata):
    dataR = []
    dataRD = {}
    result=[]
    cin = 0
    ctr = 1
    # all_keys = {k for d in newdata for k in d.keys()}
    for d in newdata:
        for key,val in d.items():
             if isinstance(val,type([])):
                    for l in val:
                        if l not in dataR:
                            dataR.append(l)
                            dataRD[(dataR[cin])] = ctr
                            ctr = ctr + 1
                            cin = cin + 1
                        d[key] = [dataRD.get(x,x) for x in d[key]]
                if isinstance(val,str):
                    if val not in dataR:
                        dataR.append(val)
                        dataRD[(dataR[cin])] = ctr
                        ctr = ctr + 1
                        cin = cin + 1
                    d[key] = [dataRD.get(x,x) for x in [d[key]]]
                                           
    return dataRD,newdata
```

Is there a better way to convert the values to numbers.
currently it is taking around 1 hour to execute this operation.

```
output:
[{'a' : [1,2],
'b':[3],
'c':[4]},
{'a' : [5,6],
'b':[7],
'c':[8]},
{'a':[2,6],
'b':[3]}]
```

Comment: what is desired output?

Comment: please add a small input/output example

Comment: It must certainly take a while... you are using 4 for loops. Also, I do not see the part where you convert the string numbers into real numbers (int or float). There are functions for that in Python.

Comment: Also, what do you mean with this "Then use that dictionary to use it as a lookup."

Comment: I have shared the output on how it should look like

Comment: @princess_hacker, so basically this a huge data set, to show the real data again, I need to use the "dataRD" which will contain values which are converted to numbers.

Comment: I think have got the answer, by converting the key/value string type to list and then in that case I need one loop.

Comment: If it works, don't forget to share pls, I'd be interested :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create `dict` for saving each str with a unique ID and append a new string in `dict` and use the store str and number. *(With this approach we iterate over dict one-time and on each iterate over item of `dict` and seeing each str if exist in `dict` use the number if not exist store a new number for that str.)*

```
def cnvrt_num(v, mem_cat):
    if isinstance(v, list):
        res = []
        for i in v:
            mem_cat[i] = mem_cat.get(i, len(mem_cat)+1)
            res.append(mem_cat[i])
    else:
        mem_cat[v] = mem_cat.get(v, len(mem_cat)+1)
        res = [mem_cat[v]]
    return res
            
mem_cat = {}
for dct in lst:
    for k,v in dct.items():
        dct[k] = cnvrt_num(v, mem_cat)

print(mem_cat)
# {'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'fine': 3, 'help': 4, 'four': 5, 'hen': 6, 'happy': 7, 'mouse': 8}

print(lst)
```

---

```
[
    {'a': [1, 2], 'b': [3], 'c': [4]}, 
    {'a': [5, 6], 'b': [7], 'c': [8]}, 
    {'a': [2, 6], 'b': [3]}
]
```

Input:

```
lst = [
    {'a' : ['one','two'],'b' : 'fine','c' : ['help']},
    {'a' : ['four','hen'],'b' : 'happy','c' : ['mouse']},
    {'a' : ['two','hen'],'b' : 'fine'}]
```